# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have a bit of a problem, I'm EXTREMELY new to PHP and I'm having a problem updating a string on my database, It's throwing out this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs......\ban.php on line 11

Here is the source:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "example";
$password = "example";
$name = "Brendan";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
$query = mysqli_query("$conn, UPDATE * wp_oxygenpurchaseusers
                  SET user_url =  '2'
                  WHERE display_name = $name");
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo $row['classtype']."<br>";
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for everyone's help :)

Comment: Remove that * from the update statement and see if it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

- First of all, you are assigning the variable `$query`, but using `$result` when trying to fetch the result.
- Secondly, you have included your connection (`$conn`), inside your query. It needs to be separated.
- Finally, you probably need to put quotes around your value.

  ```
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE * wp_oxygenpurchaseusers
                     SET user_url =  '2'
                     WHERE display_name = '$name'");
  ```

If `user_url` is always a number, you should really convert it to type `INT` instead of using a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query("$conn, UPDATE ");
```

you are passing one solid string into function, instead of 2 separate parameters. * is superfluous too.

### I WISH there was a method to remove this kind of questions right after the OP read the answer.

Instead of leaving it to hang around forever with 1 or 2 occasional votes.